# Lazy load pine script function to improve performance

Tags: performance, pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm building a pine script that allows the user to pick from many TA strategies including buy/sell/strongbuy/strongsell from tradingview technicals which is very resource heavy.

I have tried to put all calls to functions behind a question mark operator so that if they are not being used they don't use any processing resources and end up slowing down unnecessarily the script but I still cannot find any approach that works.

I also haven't been able to find any recommendation on how to implement lazy loading or lazy calling functions.

```
if true or heavy()
  do this
```

I would expect the above code to not call `heavy()` function.

Also I would have expected that this code below should not call security but it seems to me all the security calls are being executed in the script even if ALL of them are behind a disabled flag.

```
rsi1 = false ? f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, rsi1TimeFrame, ta.rsi(rsiSource, rsi1Length)) : 0.0
```

I ignore what could be the reason. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or maybe lazy loading is not supported, in any case I'd really appreciate any input! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading isn't a pinescript concept indeed
However, I found this article highlighting a few key concepts to optimize a pine script: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-optimize-pine-code

2/ With this script (https://www.tradingview.com/script/rRmrkRDr-Script-Stopwatch-PineCoders-FAQ/) you can monitor the execution time of your scripts.
Basically, it consists in capturing the timestamp before and after your code and displaying the difference of the two timestamps

Comment: thanks, thats a good one! one of the recommendations is to recycle calls of security which is something I've been considering doing, I'll give it a try

Comment: I am interested in this problem... what do you mean by: "recycle security calls"? Thank you